# How to disable cmake setting CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++1y -g -O3 -std=gnu++11

Tags: cmake, flags

cmake generates the flags.make file with

```
CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++1y -g -O3 -std=gnu++11
```

The first `-std` is set by me and the second is generated by cmake. I can't understand where the second one comes from or how to disable it.

Has someone encountered the same issue and know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Without having your code/project it's difficult to tell. Just a guess: you are including/depending on an external library that does need C++11 (e.g. Boost) and has [requested it from CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD).

So to override this with your own need for C++14 you can either set globally [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) with something like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

or with naming specific [compiler features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#manual:cmake-compile-features(7)) needed in your library/executable.

Comment: If setting `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`, you probably also want to set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` and likely `CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS` as well. It takes all three to be certain of getting the behaviour you want. Explanations of how/why they should be used together can be found [here](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/).